# capybara 2.0.2 visit doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I haven an Rspec which has the following:

```
visit '/static_pages/home'
```

It works fine under Capybara 1.1.2, now when I switch to Capybara 2.0.2 I get an NoMethod exception on visit.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you put the `require` line in `spec_helper.rb`? Also, are you using `visit` in an integration/feature spec?

Comment: Please, provide reproduction case so we can reproduce this problem and fix your code. What you provided isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

What testing framework are you using? Have you included Capybara::DSL as specified in the README?

Comment: OP mentioned using RSpec. Under RSpec, you don't need do `include Capybara::DSL`. All it's needed is to `require 'capybara/rspec'` in `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: It was indeed the require 'capybara/rspec' addition spec_helper.rb